# can you build a maven project inside of a gradle wrapper

Tags: maven, gradle

It may be just that I have a general misunderstanding how gradle build works, but it feels to me that I can not build a maven file inside of a gradle build. Since gradle uses the gradle.build file, and maven uses a pom.xml, it does not seem as though I can do this. I have multiple maven projects that I would like to wrap up with a gradle wrapper. I can not find ANYTHING on whether this is even possible.

Comment: Usually you use either Maven or Gradle but never both within the same project. Apart from that you can not run a Maven build (or to be accurate technically you could call Maven from Gradle or via versa; But I strongly discourage that)... What is the advantage of wrapping Maven projects with Gradle Wrapper would it have?

Comment: I have existing maven projects that I would prefer to build with gradle. There are many dependencies that maven handles right now, so to convert them to gradle is almost impossible.

Comment: I don't understand ..you want to go a strange way instead of simply doing once the work to migrate to Gradle or why not using Maven overall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Maven and Gradle are build tools and you should only use one of them for a given project.

If you have existing Maven projects and like the functionality provided by the Gradle wrapper, there is a similar [wrapper for Maven](https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) (note that this is currently a third-party plugin but they plan to include it in the upcoming release 3.7 of Maven).

Alternatively you could convert your projects entirely to Gradle.

Comment: so I simply can not? that is really the question. thank you though

Comment: You cannot import a Maven project in Gradle, but you can [execute external commands from Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) (and from Maven). So in theory yes, but in practice I am 95% sure you are going down the wrong path.

Comment: Thank you for the inputs. I do have a semi-workaround. it is extremely "hacky" but it is working.